# Using a function to increment a given number in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate a simple game in python. In this game, the player would throw a dice and would move from their current position towards the end line (located in position 100), depending on the dice (which is numbered from 1 to 6).

I'm trying to come up with a function that would do the following: add the current position and the result of the dice. However, if this function gives a number higher than 100, the function would ignore it and throw the dice again, since there's no positions after 100.

Below you can find the 'pseudo-code' I've come up with (half real code, half my ideas/comments):

```
import random 

def movement(current_position, distance):
        current_position = 0 #a counter should be added here I guess to increment the position
        distance = random.randint(1,6)
        move = current_position + distance
              if move > 100; do:
                  #function telling python to ignore it and throw the dice again
              elif move = 100; do:
                  print("You reached position 100")
              else:
                  return move
```

Could you help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Your pseudo-code falls short here. What if it's exactly 100? Or, if you have 99, do you just keep rolling for a 1 even though the final value is inevitable?

Comment: I guess I should include an 'elif' statement for 100 position (thanks for that! I will include it in my question). But if the position is 99, the dice should definitely be thrown again until its result is 1 and the 100 position is reached.

Comment: But you don't seem to be counting the dice rolls, so what difference does it make to use the RNG to get the final `1` or just add it on?

Comment: Are you storing these numbers anywhere for some type of statistical analysis? A computer could brute force this before we could blink.

Comment: My idea was to call this function within another function that would count the dice rolls, as you say. But I need to define it before doing that

Answer (score 1):

You could set up conditions like this where if the dice roll pushes the current value over 100 it is ignored until a dice roll creates a value equal to 100

```
from random import randint

current = 0
while current != 100:
    r = randint(1, 6)
    if current + r > 100:
        continue
    else:
        current += r
    print(current)
```

> ```
> 4
> 8
> ...
> 89
> 93
> 96
> 98
> 99
> 100
> ```

Comment: I would add a `print(current)` inside of your `else` statement to track `current` as it is incremented

Answer (score 0):

you could always check if it's over 100 and then revert to the old position. Then you'd call movement from your main function say `def playGame():`

```
def playGame():
    position = 0
    while(position != 100):
         position = movement(position)

def movement(current_position):
    distance = random.randint(1,6)
    current_position += distance
          if move > 100:
              current_position -= distance
          else:
              return current_position
```

Comment: Can I make the movement function take two parameters instead of just one? I would use movement(current_position, distance). Would this still be correct?